# get value by key dynamically from multidimensional associative array php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

iam getting "undefined index error" when trying to get the numeric value dynamically.

if have an array like this,

```
$area =  array( 
    'MetroManila' => array ('Manila'=>'133900000', 'Mandaluyong'=>'137401000', 'Marikina'=>'137402000'),
    'Bataan' =>array('Abucay'=>'030801000', 'Bagac'=>'030802000', 'Balanga'=>'030803000', ),
);
```

all i want to get is to get the numeric value from array like this
"137401000"

when i do it like echo `$area['MetroManila'][Mandaluyong];` its okay.
but when i get the value dynamically `$area[$var][$var];` it returns an undefined index error.

i have already check the value of $var and no problem with its value.

Comment: based on the array above, if you use `$area[$var][$var];` it will sure lead to undefined index, no key in your array has the same parent key and sub key. so an error is expected

Comment: Please show us the code how you created `$area[$var][$var];`

Comment: in addition to what @Scuzzy said, how do you utilize `$area[$var][$var];`? where's the rest of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two different variables, one for the first dimension, another for the second dimension. E.g.

```
$province = 'MetroManila';  
$city = 'Mandaluyong'; 
echo $area[$province][$city];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make recursive usage of a function like this

```
$area =  array( 
   'MetroManila' => array ('Manila'=>'133900000', 
'Mandaluyong'=>'137401000', 'Marikina'=>'137402000'),
'Bataan' =>array('Abucay'=>'030801000', 'Bagac'=>'030802000', 'Balanga'=>'030803000', ),
);
$arr=[];
 array_walk_recursive(
      $area, 
      function($k) use (&$arr) {
           $arr[]=$k;
       }
 );
print_r($arr);
```